# Given a large number $n$, check if it has a zero digit in base $b$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms

Given a large number $n$, check if it has a zero digit in base $b$. By large number I mean something like $2^{13579^{3597}}$ so direct computation of digits is not feasible.

Comment: If you have a way to compute this number modulo $b^k$, you can show it is has a zero by taking (hopefully) small values of $k$. For example your number has a zero digit in base 10, as can be seen by taking $k=8$. Of course this criterion is useless if the zeros are for some reason not equally distributed.